# Outlook Add-in Unable to get inbox items

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Am developing to audit mails that comes into inbox. In this am trying to wrap all the mail items in inbox with a custom class. Am using the following code to do that.

```
OutlookNS._NameSpace outNS;
        List<MailWrapper> wrappedItems = new List<MailWrapper>();
        OutlookNS.Explorer explorer;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            outNS = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            OutlookNS.MAPIFolder folder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(OutlookNS.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as OutlookNS.MAPIFolder;

            foreach (OutlookNS.MailItem item in folder.Items)//No items here
            {
                try
                {
                    OutlookNS.MailItem mailItem = item as OutlookNS.MailItem;
                    MailWrapper wrappedItem = new MailWrapper(mailItem); ;
                    wrappedItems.Add(wrappedItem);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // do nothing for now
                }
            }
        }
```

But this is not fetching any items. can somebody help please.Am guessing it could be because the mails have still not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never ever loop through all items in a folder - you will run out of RPC channels.

Most importantly, you are assuming that all items in the Inbox are `MailItem` objects. You can also have `MeetingItem`, `ReportItem`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap all items in the folder. Instead, you may handle the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813.aspx) event of the Explorer class which is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. This event also occurs when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder.

So basically you can wrap an item when it is selected (comes into view) in Outlook. You may also find the [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

As a workaround you may keep a list of `EntryID` which can be used to retrieve the original item by using the `GetItemFromID` method of the Namespace class.

Also I have noticed the following line of code:

```
 foreach (OutlookNS.MailItem item in folder.Items)//No items here
```

The `Items` collection may contains different type of Outlook items. You need to check the [MessageClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867813(v=office.15).aspx) property or just check the item type (VBA):

```
 For Each Item In olFolder.Items
   If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
     Debug.Print oMail.SenderEmailAddress
   End If
 Next
```